# How Append a table from pandas data frame without truncating old data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-to-sql

I have  a table `rate_card` as shown below which I have inserted from data-frame using

```
 df5.to_sql('rate_card', cnx, if_exists='replace', schema='asia', index = False,method='multi')
```

**Current data inside table**

```
ORG_CNTY  DEST_CNTY   KG  Cost    Version
 DE         FR         1   50     2019-12-02
 DE         FR         2   80     2019-12-02
 DE         IND        2   65     2018-12-01
 DE         US         1   70     2019-12-01
```

I have new set data which need to insert to table again

**New data**

```
ORG_CNTY  DEST_CNTY   KG  Cost    Version
 DE         FR         1   60     2020-06-02
 DE         FR         2   90     2020-06-02
 DE         IND        1   55     2020-06-02
 DE         US         1   80     22020-06-02
```

**Expected Output**

```
ORG_CNTY  DEST_CNTY   KG  Cost    Version
 DE         FR         1   50     2019-12-02
 DE         FR         2   80     2019-12-02
 DE         IND        2   65     2018-12-01
 DE         US         1   70     2019-12-01
 DE         FR         1   60     2020-06-02
 DE         FR         2   90     2020-06-02
 DE         IND        1   55     2020-06-02
 DE         US         1   80     22020-06-02
```

my current code is truncating and loading the table new data. I want to old data and append the new data into the table. How can this done in python?

Comment: change the `if_exists='replace'` to `if_exists='append'`

Comment: @Datanovice, if need append only based on specific keys. is there something more that i need to do.

Comment: then you should push the data into a staging table and invoke a stored procedure to update your table based on your keys. you could also pull the whole table down into pandas and update it from there.

Comment: @Datanovice, could show a example

Comment: your current data is jsut a product of both the tables ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df_expected = df_current.append(df_new)
```